# POA chain: intrinsic gas too low, contract deployment

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, private-blockchain, json-rpc, poa

I'm trying to deploy my smart contract to a private proof of authority chain with geth, but i always get the following error message **intrinsic gas too low**

This is the JSON RPC request i'm sending. `bytecode` is the byte code of my smart contract.

```
data = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_sendTransaction",
    "params": [{
         "from": w3.eth.defaultAccount,
         "data": Web3.toHex(bytecode),
    }],
    "id": 420
}
```

When I deploy the same contract on ropsten it uses **3163322** gas. [Ropsten link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x497b63e3d812f9a542ee80892362c70277c6d1de48f4bd5e988f2552b6206922)

I'm able to deploy smaller contract like SafeMath, so my first thought was that the gaslimit of my blocks were too small. This is not the case.

> eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit
>
> **150063322**

Does anyone see the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {
     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "method": "eth_sendTransaction",
     "params": [{
          "from": w3.eth.defaultAccount,
          "data": Web3.toHex(bytecode),
          "gas": Web3.toHex(8000000),
     }],
     "id": 420
}
```

Ok, **gas** should be added to the params, I added it to data, that did not work